# Extract only the left or the right channel of the audio of an video on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I was trying to extract only the left or the right channel of the audio of an video on iOS. I have done couple research but couldn't really find a solution. Does anybody have a idea how to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with Audio Unit Services